# Adding content in google API map multiple infowindows (marker in an array)

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm wrtting an API v3 map with multiple markers and multiple infoWindows. 
I wanted to be able to jump from an InfoWindows to the other with a link. I used the code of Wolfgang Pichler

although I want to add a different picture and a description in content of each infowindows.

---

I'v try to add and image in the maker array :

```
  var data = [ // Data of points and coords of sprite icons
   { name:"Germany", lat:"51.179342", lng:"10.50292", top: 64, left: 32, img:"imgs/D1/01-barbes.jpg" },
];
```

---

Then to put it in Create Marker function :

```
function createMarker(point, top, left, name, i, img) {

  var g = google.maps;
  var base = "http://sites.google.com/site/mxamples/icons-dot.png";
  var image = { url: base,
   size: new g.Size(32, 32),
   origin: new g.Point(top, left),
   anchor: new g.Point(15, 32) };
   var photos = img;
```

---

and fanilly to add it to the content of my infowindows :

```
  var html ="<div class='infowindow'>" +
  "<h3 class='firstHeading'>"+ name + "<\/i><span><\/span><\/h3>"+
  "<div class='bodyWin'>"+ photos +
  "<p>My friend Addi is sitting on his chair waiting for customers." +
  "<\/p>"+
  "<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='infoopen(event, " + i + ")'>Next step<\/a>" +
  "<\/div>"+
  "<\/div>";
```

But it return "undefined"

He is my example on a jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/coraMashed/kohceobm/1/

Is anyone can help. I've been through all the API doccumentation and on stackoverflow question, but I've find anything
taht use the same code.

Thank you very much

Comment: I get an error in your fiddle `Uncaught ReferenceError: infoopen is not defined`.  If I fix that, [it works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/kohceobm/2/)

Comment: Thank you. I fixed that too [link](https://jsfiddle.net/coraMashed/kohceobm/4/) but the image (i try also with text) still return me "undefined". How can i fixe that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem. Here is the full code that you can use : [link](https://jsfiddle.net/coraMashed/kohceobm/13/)

```
// Globals
var map, iw;
var gmarkers = [];



function createMarker(point, top, left, name, i, img, descr) {

  var g = google.maps;
  var base = "http://sites.google.com/site/mxamples/icons-dot.png";
  var image = { url: base,
   size: new g.Size(32, 32),
   origin: new g.Point(top, left),
   anchor: new g.Point(15, 32) };
   var photos = img;

  /* shadows are deprecated since API version 3.14
  var shadow = { url: base,
    size: new g.Size(59, 32),
    origin: new g.Point(192, 32),
    anchor: new g.Point(15, 32) };
  */





  var marker = new g.Marker({ position: point,
    map: map, title: name, clickable: true,
    draggable: false, icon: image
  });




  var html ="<div class='infowindow'>" +
  "<h3 class='firstHeading'>"+ name + "<\/i><span>"+point+"<\/span><\/h3>"+
  "<div class='bodyWin'>"+ "<img src='imgs/pix/"+img+".jpg' />" +
  "<p>" + descr +
  "<\/p>"+ 
  "<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='infoopen(event, " + i + ")'>< Next step<\/a>" +
  "<\/div>"+
  "<\/div>";




  // Store markers content as property of gmarkers
  marker.content = html;
  gmarkers.push(marker);

  g.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
   iw.setContent(marker.content);
   iw.open(map, this);
  });
}


function infoopen(e, nr) {

  // Adjust the number
  if (nr < gmarkers.length-1) { nr+= 1; }
  else { nr = 0; }

// iw.setContent(gmarkers[nr].content);
// iw.open(map, gmarkers[nr]);
   google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[nr], "click");

   // Stop the event from bubbling to the map and trigger a click event.
   // This is a Maps API regression bug.
   if (e && e.cancelable) e.stopPropagation();
 //  if (window.event) event.cancelBubble = true;
}


function buildMap() {

  var g = google.maps;

  var data = [ // Data of points and coords of sprite icons
   { name:"Germany", lat:"51.179342", lng:"10.50292", top: 64, left: 32, img:"image01", descr:"This is my text 1" },
   { name:"Netherlands", lat:"52.54963", lng:"6.29516", top: 0, left: 0, img:"image02", descr:"This an other text 2" },
   { name:"Belgium", lat:"50.84854", lng:"4.3517", top: 96, left: 0, img:"image03", descr:"This an other text 3" },
   { name:"France", lat:"46.69466", lng:"2.48291", top: 32, left: 0, img:"image04", descr:"This an other text 4" },
   { name:"Austria", lat:"47.591346", lng:"14.545898", top: 0, left: 32, img:"image05", descr:"This an other text 5" },
   { name:"Madrid", lat:"40.464774", lng:"-3.696540", top: 0, left: 32, img:"image04", descr:"This an other text 6" }
  ];

  var opts_map = {
    center: new g.LatLng(50, 8),
    zoom: 5,
    mapTypeId: g.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    scaleControl: true,
    streetViewControl: false,

   mapTypeControlOptions: {
    mapTypeIds: [ g.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, g.MapTypeId.SATELLITE, g.MapTypeId.TERRAIN]
   }
  };
  map = new g.Map(document.getElementById("map"), opts_map);
  iw = new g.InfoWindow();

  // v2 behaviour
  g.event.addListener(map, "click", function() {
    if (iw) iw.close();
//  alert("map click triggered");
  });

  // Load all markers
  for (var i = 0, n; n = data[i]; i++) {
   var point = new g.LatLng(parseFloat(n.lat), parseFloat(n.lng));
   createMarker(point, n.top, n.left, n.name, i, n.img, n.descr);
  }

}

window.onload = buildMap;
```